# Using 3rd party libraries in Angular4 components, specifically vexflow

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm just starting out trying to build a music application in Angular4, and I wanted to use the Js library vexflow. I was just starting to learn how to use the thing, when I'm getting weird assignment errors in my component. I'm literally following the vexflow tutorial (while translating to a exported class syntax) and getting errors. I'm wondering if I imported the library correctly. Here's the steps I took:

```
npm install vexflow --save
npm install @types/vexflow --save-dev
```

I added vexflow to my types in the tsconfig.app.json file here:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "vexflow"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Here is my component with the tutorial inside:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as vexflow from 'vexflow';

@Component({
  selector: 'p-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  VF = Vex.Flow;
// Create an SVG renderer and attach it to the DIV element named "boo".
  div = document.getElementById("ogStaff")
  renderer = new this.VF.Renderer(this.div, this.VF.Renderer.Backends.SVG);

  // Configure the rendering context.
  this.renderer.resize(500, 500);
  var context = this.renderer.getContext();
  context.setFont("Arial", 10, "").setBackgroundFillStyle("#eed");

  // Create a stave of width 400 at position 10, 40 on the canvas.
  var stave = new this.VF.Stave(10, 40, 400);

  // Add a clef and time signature.
  stave.addClef("treble").addTimeSignature("4/4");

  // Connect it to the rendering context and draw!
  stave.setContext(context).draw();
}
```

What you can't see here is that under the this.renderer on the sixteenth line, there is an error underneath the this. It says:

[ts] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

I'm wondering if I'm importing this library properly, and why it's not understanding when I'm assigning instance variables.

In this example, If I assign "renderer" (on line 13) as "var renderer", the program gives me the same error as above, but below, for "context" (line 17), it throws an error if I don't add var. I'm a little confused if this is my IDE or the way I've included this library.

Comment: To start, I'd suggest implementing onInit, and putting all 'logic' into an onInit function, as described here. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnInit-class.html

Comment: This pointed me to whatever the problem was. Some of these variables need to be set as Ivars and others need to be local to the function (in this case just the ngOnInit function. Thanks.